# MySQL intervals dates remaining

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I have to write a query that pulls the users that are ten days away from ending their free trial. My question is, do i do a `minus 10 day interval` or a `plus 10 day interval` against `CURRENT_DATE()`.

I am having difficulty thinking about this.

Here's my query:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE freetrial=1 AND date_format(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY`

Comment: What data type is the `date_created` column in?

Comment: date_created is TIMESTAMP

Comment: Try it both ways and see what makes sense, then you don't have to "think" about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trial period is 30 days long then you need to add 20 days to the date they registered and compare that to today's date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE freetrial=1 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 20 DAY = CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: Ill try that. But Im trying to understand if I should be using a minus or a plus and why

Comment: Do you store the date when the trial ends? That's the date you should be using.

Comment: yes. the data never leaves. im trying to understand if i should be using a minus interval or a plus interval to determine if the user is 10 days away from expiration

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains the end of their free trial? or, how long is the free trial?

Comment: the free trial is 30 days from the date_created field

Comment: So with that theory, if i wanted to find all the users that have been using the application for a week, I'd do: $sql="`SELECT * FROM users WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK = CURRENT_DATE()`";

Comment: One last question. I have a case where we email the client if they are one day away from expiration. Id like to just do + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, but I need 1 day prior to 1 month. Being that there are different number of days in one month, how do I accomplish this with your method?

Comment: Typically "one month" means "30 days". If you start going by actually days in the month, not only does the coding get harder, it gets confusing for your users. I'd recommend sticking to one month equaling 30 days for everybody's sanity.